# Cannot change transform during play mode

Tags: unity-game-engine, interaction

I want to change the XR Grab Interactable Attach point during play mode in unity 2021.3.24f1. I have attach the XR Grab Interactable script to a gun 3d model including Box Collider and Rigid body. in previously used version by me it was working perfectly I was able to move the attach point (which is empty game object). This attach point is child game object of the gun with only transform component is attach which is by default. The position (0,0,0) and rotation(0,0,0) of of attach point is set then the gun is set and shown in pic 1. now I have to change and the transform of attach point and set it as I am holding the gun in hand and I have to do it in play mode so that I can change and see weather I am holding it at perfect position nor not simultaneously.[Pic 1 Holding gun with attach point at (0,0,0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KEOn.png). [Pic 2 Holding gun with attach point at (0,0.5,0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzW8r.png)[Pic 2 Holding gun with attach point at (0,0.5,0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMZiS.png). I have to remove headset and exit play mode to change position and rotation so that gun set perfectly to my hand.

I have tried using custom script from the **Valem Tutorials** Youtube channel (https://youtu.be/nowlPXuPEG8?t=224) for holding game object in both hands this is also not working. I am attaching XR Grab Interactable script which come when we install XR Interaction toolkit from the package manager.

Answer (score 1):

In XR Grab Interactable -> attachment point compatibility -> select legacy. This will make sure it's working